# conditional elseif statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, dplyr

I have a data framethat looks like this

```
Animal
species sum
A       2
A       6
B       8
B       1
C       6
C       3
D       5
D       4
```

I wants the code that divides the min sum by the max sum for each species and creates a new column called ratio, and if that number is greater than .2 I want it to return that ratio, but if it is smaller than .2, I want it to return NA.
I would like to do this in dplyr
This is the code I have currently but it is not working
I have this string of commands in R

```
animal <- animal %>% 
+     group_by(species) %>% 
+     mutate(ratio = ifelse((min(sum)/max(sum) > .2), (min(sum)/max(sum)), "NA"))
```

Thanks!

This is what it should look like in the end

```
species sum   ratio
A       2   .333
A       6   .333
B       8    NA
B       1    NA
C       6    .5
C       3    .5
D       5    .8
D       4    .8
```

Comment: You are using a string "NA" instead of a real NA.  If you want to subset the dataset later, it is better to a real NA which works with `is.na` and other functions

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid `ifelse` because both you will have to evaluate the whole vector anyway, and because you need to calculate the whole process twice. Here's how I would do this

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Animal)[, ratio := {r <- range(sum); r[1L]/r[2L]}, by = species]
Animal[ratio <= .2, ratio := NA]
#    species sum     ratio
# 1:       A   2 0.3333333
# 2:       A   6 0.3333333
# 3:       B   8        NA
# 4:       B   1        NA
# 5:       C   6 0.5000000
# 6:       C   3 0.5000000
# 7:       D   5 0.8000000
# 8:       D   4 0.8000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NA_real_` to make the types compatible

```
 animal %>% 
  group_by(species) %>% 
  mutate(ratio= ifelse((min(sum)/max(sum))> .2,
      round((min(sum)/max(sum)),2), NA_real_))
#  species sum ratio
#1       A   2  0.33
#2       A   6  0.33
#3       B   8    NA
#4       B   1    NA
#5       C   6  0.50
#6       C   3  0.50
#7       D   5  0.80
#8       D   4  0.80
```

A base R option would be

```
animal$ratio <-  with(animal, ave(sum, species, FUN=function(x) {
                  x1 <- min(x)/max(x)
                  NA^(x1 <= 0.2)*x1 }))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    animal <- animal %>% 
            group_by(species) %>% 
             mutate(ratio = ifelse((min(sum)/max(sum) > .2), (min(sum)/max(sum)), as.numeric(NA)))

> animal
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: species

  species sum     ratio
1       A   2 0.3333333
2       A   6 0.3333333
3       B   8        NA
4       B   1        NA
5       C   6 0.5000000
6       C   3 0.5000000
7       D   5 0.8000000
8       D   4 0.8000000
```